# Two problems on Autonomus ODE properties of unknow solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have to explain a student two exercises but I don't know how continue at the first and how start at the second one.

20. Let $f(x)$ continously differentiable and such that $f(0)=0$. Show that the solutions of $x'=f(x)h(t)$ cannot change sign.

**My attemp**:
As $f$ is cont. diff. we know that $f$ is continous and also $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=f'(x)$, then for the existence and unicity theorem we have a unique solution $x(t)$. Since $f(0)=0$ we have that $t=0$ is an extreme value for $x(t)$. On a graph, I can see that $x(t)$ cannot change sign independent of the extreme value, and I know that we have to use the product $f(x)h(t)$ and law of signs but I can see how.

22. Find the limits as $t\rightarrow \pm \infty$, of the solution $\phi(t)$ of the ivp $x'=(x+2)(1-x^4)$, with $x(0)=0$.

**I'm lost at this one**

The first idea that came out to me are *using algebra we can put:* $x'=(x+2)(1+x)(1-x)(1+x^2)$ via partial fractions we can get an antiderivative and then estimate that limits, but this appears a lot of  unnecessary work. There's an elegant way to get this excersice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second one, simply looking at the sign of $x'$ in different intervals gives you the **phase portrait**, where you should be able to easily read off where you end up if you start at $x=0$:
$$
\longrightarrow
\quad
-2
\quad
\longleftarrow
\quad
-1
\quad
\longrightarrow
\quad
1
\quad
\longleftarrow
$$